# Hoping for a custom recovery (CWM or TWRP) for galaxy tab 4 10.1

Tags: cyanogenmod, clockworkmod-recovery, samsung-galaxy-tab-10, twrp

I was hoping to tweak our tab like my s3 mini, but I can't find recoveries for it and came to the conclusion the device is still too new?

There certainly are tab 10.1 things mentioned but I'm assuming these are first generation tabs?

Answer (score 1):

There are custom recoveries for your device but they are only available for the Wi-Fi only Galaxy Tab 4 10.1-

[TWRP (SM-T530), odin/heimdall flash](http://forum.xda-developers.com/tab-4/orig-development/twrp-2-7-1-0-galaxy-tab-4-10-1-sm-t530-t2830798)

[CWM (SM-T530), odin/heimdall flash](http://forum.xda-developers.com/tab-4/orig-development/clockworkmod-6-0-5-0-galaxy-tab-4-10-1-t2830683)

**